# The alert statements in the javascript do not show up?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The following javacript is used for validation checking. However the alert 
  statements do not appear when there is missing input. 
  I  tried to delete the if statement and use only the alert statement and the 
  script works fine.
  Is there anything wrong with the if statements?
  Below is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A More Complex Form with JavaScript Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Validation form
function validate_form()
{
    valid = true;
    // check for missing name
    if ( document.contact_form.contact_name.value == "" )
    {
        alert("Please fill in the 'Your Name' box,");
        valid = false;
    }
    // check for missing gender
    if ( document.contact_form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( 
    document.contact_form.gender[1].checked == false )  
    {
        alert("Please choose your Gender: Male or Female");
        valid = false;
    }
    // check for missing age
    if ( document.contact_form.age.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert("Please select your Age.");
        valid = false;
    }
    // check for missing terms 
    if ( document.contact_form.terms == false )
    {
        alert("Please check the Terms & Conditions box.");
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
//-->        
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Please Enter Your Details Below</h1>
<form name="contact_form" onsubmit="validate_form()">
<p>Your Name: 
<input type="text" name="contact_name" size="20">
</p>
<p>
Your Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
</p>
<p>
Your Age:
<select name="age">
<option value="1">0-14 years</option>
<option value="2">15-30 years</option>
<option value="3">31-44 years</option>
<option value="4">45-60 years</option>
<option value="5">61-74 years</option>
<option value="6">75-90 years</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
Do you agree to the Terms and Conditions?
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="yes">Yes
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Details">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any developer tools console errors?

Comment: It works after you fix the syntax error. Some recommendations: Only use one alert at the end, so just concat all the strings inside the alerts into one string and alert it at the end. Users dont like egtting 4 popups telling the same thing. Also, the terms check doesn't work, you have to add .checked to it as well. Atm, you can submit without the terms being accepted, after the synatx error is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( document.contact_form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( 
document.contact_form.gender[1].checked == false )  
{
    alert("Please choose your Gender: Male or Female");
    valid = false;
}
```

you have to change if condition like that

```
if ( document.contact_form.gender[0].checked == false &&
document.contact_form.gender[1].checked == false )  
{
    alert("Please choose your Gender: Male or Female");
    valid = false;
}
```

Your script can't fire up because of this mistake.

Tip: You can check script errors from dev-console of browsers like Chrome Console.

as  "trincot" said by comment, you can also use `!` operator to check `boolean` values like that.

```
if ( !document.contact_form.gender[0].checked && !document.contact_form.gender[1].checked )  
{
    alert("Please choose your Gender: Male or Female");
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: You could also say that `== false` can be checked in a more "professional" way with the not (`!`) operator: `!document.contact_form.gender[0].checked && !.....` (+1)